# When I use drain cleaner the whole house smells like sulfur for a couple hours

Tags: plumbing

I used it in the bathtub, & another time in the basement suds tub, the whole house would smell. Last year I checked the vent pipe on the roof & removed a lot of old paper wasp nests, but am still having the problem.

Comment: What kind of pipes do you have? Are they copper / steel / cast or PVC?

Despite what the bottle says, Drano can eat certain metals and cause toxic fumes in your house while it does it.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against Drano. The sulfur smell you are smelling is because it is mainly composed of Sulfuric Acid. If you smell it throughout your house it might be damaging your pipes.

To clear a clog I would recommend a plunger and a drain snake before resorting to any acids. If those do not work I would recommend a plumber.

However, be cautious now. If you are manually clearing your pipes, anything that you pull out might be covered in acid, so make sure to use hand, eye, and nose/mouth protection.

Comment: That would make sense, I see some of the manufacturers have come out with the "gel" version advertised as safe on pipes,

Comment: It looks like it is doing it on 2 separate vent pipes, one in the basement, the other on the bathroom

Comment: [Drano is lye-based](https://blog.jiffyondemand.com/why-plumbers-advise-against-drano/), not acidic and not sulfuric.